How to do a search involving key words and years in Excel?
I have a large dataset (6,000 rows by 40 columns) that contains a column of key words and another column for fiscal years.
I want to use a filter function that returns all rows that contain a particular key word in a particular fiscal year. Here's a 3x3 example:



Project Name
Key Words
Fiscal Year




Market and Policy Analysis
Economics.mothers.food
2018


Regional potato disease
Potato.economics.disease
2020


Farmer's markets
Potato.onion.tomatoes
2020



So if I searched this dataset for potato and 2020 I would filter out two projects.

either convert you data to a table, or use the ribbon: data>filter

I notice potato as well in first column. Is that to be factored in? which means that word may occur in any of the other 39 or 38 columns? Also how KeyWord column is to be used? You have Potato.onion.tomatoes as an entry in Key Word column but you are only searching for potato

In other words, Search is to be done only on Key Words column or all 39 columns including Key Words and 40th column is your Year, please confirm.

Good questions.  Yes, potato may appear elsewhere in the dataset, but I only want to search the column with the key words in it.  How do you convert the data into a table?

Something like this should work: =FILTER(A2:C4,1-ISERR(SEARCH(".potato.","."&B2:B4&".")*(C2:C4=2020)))

@GrigPerry Create and format tables

Yes, that looks to be headed in the right direction.  How do I generalize this formula to allow me to set the search terms external to the formula?  So I enter "potato" in cell a1 and "2020" in cell a2, with my data in cells A3:C5?

@GrigPerry it should be like this: =FILTER(A3:C5,1-ISERR(SEARCH("."&A1&".","."&B3:B5&".")*(C3:C5=A2)),"Oops not found") and updated in answers

You could try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell A6
=FILTER(A2:C4,(1-ISERR(SEARCH(".potato.","."&B2:B4&".")))*(C2:C4=2020),"")


With reference to OPs comments
=FILTER(A3:C5,(1-ISERR(SEARCH("."&A1&".","."&B3:B5&".")))*(C3:C5=A2),"")


Updated screenshot:

Works as expected!

Ah yes, that sort of works.  When I changed the search to  mothers and left the year at 2020, it should have come back with an empty set.  Instead it came back with the first line, i.e., it ignored my year.  So the key word search is working, the fiscal year isn't.

@GrigPerry see my updated screenshot it works as expected. If i am not missing any!

Ah, that's the ticket!  Works great!

@GrigPerry please ensure to accept the answer by ticking the check mark beside. Thank You Very Much!

Now for a bit of a tweak I need to add and it will be good to go.  I need to be able to enter partial key words and have it kick out everything that matches.  So if I type "moth" it will give me everything with "moth" in it, including mother and mothers.  I think this involves using ISNUMBER function

Using ISNUMBER() or 1-ISERR() works the same way. Since the first one has more characters than the second, so i have used the second one. the formulas posted should work as expected for you. Please try and let me know.

@GrigPerry ok, so if you type only moth instead of mother(s) then we need to remove those extra characters before in the formulas, then the formula will be like : =FILTER(A4:C6,(1-ISERR(SEARCH(A1,B4:B6)))*(C4:C6=A2),"") this doesn;t includes those added brackets to enclose specific and exclusive words with in the dot brackets. the above formula will return anything which starts or ends with or contains moth

If the data is in an Excel table (here the standard name is Table1), and the searched parameters are named: Key_Word and Fiscal_Year, then you can use the following formula:
=FILTER(Table1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("."&Key_Word&".","."&Table1[Key Words]&"."))*(Table1[Fiscal Year]=Fiscal_Year))

You can add headers to the result as needed.


Indeed, that works!  A million thanks, I've spent days trying to make this work.
